# App crash after changing permission

Tags: swift, xcode

I try to create my first app and i have the following issue. I use the Contact Framework and the ContactPicker to pick email addresses from contacts. In my first step i ask the user for authorization like.

```
        // Check auth state for contacts
        let store = CNContactStore()
        switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts) {
        case .Authorized:
            self.authContacts = true
            break
        case .NotDetermined:
            store.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts, completionHandler: { (succeeded, err) in
                guard err == nil && succeeded else{
                    return
                }
                self.authContacts = true
            })
            break
        default:
            self.authContacts = false
            break
        }
```

Everything runs fine and smooth. But if i change the permission on xcode emulator to deny the access to my contacts, the app crashes. The "AppDelegate.swift"  files open and the following line is marked with an red background.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

But i do not see any error message on the console. So i want know, is this a normal issue? If a restart the xcode simulator everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change permissions from outside the app (for example at the device settings, or at the simulator) - the app will crash.
This is the normal behaviour.

Comment: But why google apps don't behave like that?
I mean, they don't crash.